# Understanding date of astronomical events

Tags: equinox

I have a masters in chemistry but pretty much, a layman in astronomy.

So, can you please explain to a novice like me, about this paragraph taken from the Wikipedia article on [Makar Sankranti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makar_Sankranti):

> There are two different systems to calculate the Makara Sankranti date: *nirayana* (without adjusting for precession of equinoxes, tropical) and *sayana* (with adjustment, sidereal). The January 14 date is based on the *nirayana* system, while the *sayana* system typically computes to about December 23, per most Siddhanta texts for Hindu calendars.

Am I correct to understand that when the date was assigned in Hinduism some thousand (?) years back, the winter solistice used to be on 14th/15th January?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precession of equinoxes means that the North pole of the Earth is changing its direction. This also means, that the dates of the seasons (seen from outside the Solar System (= sidereal)) are changing. *Nirayana* calculates the date of Makar Sankranti with adding years to the first Makar Sankranti, but *sayana* calculates the date of Makar Sankranti relative to stars (sidereal).

In a nutshell: *nirayana* is on the same *date* as the first event (first Makar Sankranti), but *sayana* is on the same *event* as the first Makar Sankranti (winter solstice). Yes, winter solstice was once on the 14 January.